# How to count in which number of working hours something was done

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, data-analysis

So I am a data analyst intern and my company has given me a tast to analyse in power BI how well does our helpdesk manage to solve queries. I got the data for when the queries was created and completed and have created a column with the total hours between the creation and completion of a query. Problem is I am meant to show how many WORKING hours(8:00 am to 4:00 pm) did it take to solve the query. How do I alter the code to consider that? For example if the query started on 8:45 am 11.03.2021 and was finished at 10:45 12.03.2021 my column shows that it took 26 hours to solve while it was 10 in working hours. For now I have used the DATEDIFF function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DATEDIFF twice, once to measure the time between start and end in hours, and once to count the days. If the query took more than a day you can subtract 16 hours for each day (4 PM to 8 AM) as such:

```
DATEDIFF( <start_date>, <end_date>, HOUR ) - DATEDIFF( <start_date>, <end_date>, DAY ) * 16
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question tho, how do I get rid of weekends?